# Convert Byte array to Binary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, typed-arrays

I have a TypedArray of bytes in JavaScript, and I need to convert this into binary, in order to send to a USB device in a Chrome extension using [`chrome.usb.controlTransfer`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb.html#method-controlTransfer).

Simplified Example:

```
var message = new Uint8Array(3);
message[0] = 1;
message[1] = 2;
message[3] = 3;

var transferInfo = {
    direction: 'out',
    recipient: 'device',
    requestType: 'standard',
    request: 0,
    value: 0,
    index: 0,
    data: message
};

// 'device' is a valid handle to a device found with chrome.usb.findDevices
chrome.usb.controlTransfer(device, transferInfo, function(r) { console.log(r); });
```

This gives me the error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property 'data':
>   Expected 'binary' but got 'object'.

I'm not sure how to get from `Uint8Array` to whatever is considered to be 'binary' in JavaScript.  It's possible this is something chrome-specific, but I can't find any examples of calling this function in this way either.

I've seen the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data#Sending_typed_arrays_as_binary_data), but this appears to be specific to sending data via XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I missed the example [within the Chrome documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_hardware.html#control_transfers).

```
var message = new Uint8Array(3);
message[0] = 1;
message[1] = 2;
message[3] = 3;

var binaryMessage = message.buffer;
```